# mongodb 4.2.8 connection refused on mac Catalina OS

Tags: mongodb

I've installed mongdodb v4.2.8 (current) but i am running some issues

1. unable to write "mkdir /data/db
2. though it's already installed as i can see the version that is running but it refused to connect to port 127...:27017.

I've been following the possible solution from mongodb documentation and their solution; checking the system preferences but still can't connect or open mongodb. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

rsb

Comment: what errors are you getting for both points?

Comment: Errors 1) mkdir -p /data/db   -> mkdir:  Read-only file system 2) connection refused

Comment: For 1st its obvious you dont have write permissions grant write access to the user try `sudo`

Comment: Use the -dbpath parameter to mongod to point it to a different directory. You cannot write to /usr on Catalina.